# A better way of writing (javascript)

Tags: javascript, oop, class, function, object

Probably a lack of understanding of javascript here:

```
engine.keyboard = {};   // keyboard object

engine.keyboard.key = {
_pressed: {},

UP: 38,
DOWN: 40,
LEFT: 37,
RIGHT: 39,

isDown: function(keyCode)
{
    return this._pressed[keyCode];
},

onKeyDown: function(event)
{
    this._pressed[event.keyCode] = true;
},

onKeyUp: function(event)
{
    delete this._pressed[event.keyCode];
}

}

engine.keyboard.addListeners = function()
{
window.addEventListener('keydown', engine.keyboard.key.onKeyDown, false);
window.addEventListener('keyup', engine.keyboard.key.onKeyUp, false);
}
```

When I call, `engine.keyboard.key.isDown(38)`, I get an error that `this._pressed` is undefined.

Perhaps there is a better way of defining all these? I'm working on a very basic game but just experimenting with different ways of splitting it all up. So at the moment, I have `engine`, `engine.keyboard`, `engine.camera` and `engine.map` which all do there own tiny bits. I've used the same `engine.EXAMPLE = {}` at the start of each one. Perhaps this is inefficient?

Cheers.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but won't your `isDown()` method return either `true` or `undefined`? It will (probably, depending on how you use it) still work, but to my way of thinking it would be nicer to return `true` or `false`, which you could do with `return this._pressed[keyCode] || false;`.

Comment: Does that make an improvement to performance out of interest or just better from a coding point of view? Good comment though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are only passing the function as event handler. By doing so it has no relation to the `engine.keyboard.key` object anymore.

What `this` inside a function refers to depends on how it is called. In order for `this` to refer to `engine.keyboard.key`, the function has to be called like

```
engine.keyboard.key.onKeyDown()
```

So what you need is:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    engine.keyboard.key.onKeyDown(event);
}, false);

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    engine.keyboard.key.onKeyUp(event);
}, false);
```

Also note that `addEventListener` is not available in up to IE8. There you have to use `attachEvent`.

I suggest to read the [excellent articles about event handling on qurirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

---

**Further suggestion:**

To decouple the function from the object in a way, you can create a closure:

```
engine.keyboard = {};  
engine.keyboard.key = (function() {
    var _pressed = {};

    var key = {
        UP: 38,
        DOWN: 40,
        LEFT: 37,
        RIGHT: 39,

        isDown: function(keyCode)  {
            return _pressed[keyCode];
        },

        onKeyDown: function(event) {
            _pressed[event.keyCode] = true;
        },

        onKeyUp: function(event) {
            delete _pressed[event.keyCode];
        }
    }
    return key;
}());
```

Here there is no problem to pass `engine.keyboard.key.onKeyDown` as the functions don't rely on `this` anymore. `_pressed` is now a variable in scope the functions are defined in, so they have all access to it.

This is just to show what can be done.

Comment: Can I just clarify, how does the ----= (function---- extra ( work? And what do the final () brackets do?

Comment: @ChrisEvans: This is a self-invoking or immediate function. You define a function and execute it immediately. E.g. these two are the same: `function bar(){alert(1);}; bar();` and `(function bar(){alert(1);}())`. As you probably know, by appending `()` to a function, you are calling it, and instead of assigning the function to a variable first, you call it immediately.

Comment: Wow, fantastic answer. I had read about immediate functions but just the way it appeared on screen I couldn't make any sense of it. I'll up vote your answers when I am eventually allowed!

Comment: @ChrisEvans: Well, you can accept it ;) (by clicking the tick outline next to it). This way you also mark the question as solved.

Answer (score -1):

That's a standard key handler. I do not believe there is a better way to do things.

Comment: That does not really answer the OP's question. Why is he getting the error?